# Diagnostic settings to log latest status of each Azure Data Factory Pipeline run

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I have an ADF Pipeline that runs once every day. I use Diagnostic settings to log pipeline runs and use the following kusto query:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

I see the following results:

[image]

Is there a way to display **only** the last status (**Succeeded/Failed**) for each pipeline run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`arg_max()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction).

for example:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by runId
```